# Chat widget tawk.to blocked by chrome

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools, jquery-cookie, samesite, cross-site

I am using a chat widget from  "tawk.to". It is giving a javascript way to append the chat widget in the html page.
The javascript way is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
   (function(){
      var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s1.async=true;
      s1.src='**** link to account ***';
      s1.charset='UTF-8';
      s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
      s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
   })();
</script>
```

Now it is blocked by chrome by showing a warning as below:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://tawk.to/ was
> set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome
> now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
> with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
> tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Any idea about the issue ??

Comment: If you change origin to `https://tawk.to/` in the script what happens?

Comment: s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/<some_id>/default';
Only here i am defining the twak.to